# TFLearn: Create a Train Test set using Only tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm using my own dataset and I want to do a Deep Neural Network using tflearn.

This is a part of my code.

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv

#Load the CSV File    
X, Y = load_csv('data.csv')

#Split Data in train and Test with tflearn
```

**¿How could I do a function in TFLearn to split X, Y and get train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y ?**

I know how to do with numpy and other libraries, but I would like to do using tflearn.

Comment: If you can do it in numpy I assume you are familiar with slicing. Tensorflow implements [slicing](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining) functionality for tensors.

Comment: I don't know this functionality. I would like to do with TFLearn and using random samples. ¿Is that possible?

Comment: You can use tensorflow toghether with tflearn, I think that's why tflearn doesn't implement slicing, but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

In the `fit` method for the `tflearn.DNN` model in tflearn (http://tflearn.org/models/dnn/), you can set the option `validation_set` to a float less than 1, and then the model will automatically split your input in a training and validation set, while training.

## Example

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv

#Load the CSV File    
X, Y = load_csv('data.csv')

# Define some network
network = ... 

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=20, validation_set=0.1) # will use 10% for validation
```

This will create a validation set while training, which is different from a test set. If you just want a train and test set, I recommend taking a look at the [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function from sklearn, which also can split your data for you.

Comment: Yeah! It is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Nicki is the simplest solution i think.

But, another easy solution is to use sklearn and the train_test_split()

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
data, target = load_raw_data(data_size) # own method, data := ['hello','...'] target := [1 0 -1] label
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Or the numpy version:

```
import numpy as np
texts, target = load_raw_data(data_size) # own method, texts := ['hello','...'] target := [1 0 -1] label
train_indices = np.random.choice(len(target), round(0.8 * len(target)), replace=False)
test_indices = np.array(list(set(range(len(target))) - set(train_indices)))
x_train = [x for ix, x in enumerate(texts) if ix in train_indices]
x_test = [x for ix, x in enumerate(texts) if ix in test_indices]
y_train = np.array([x for ix, x in enumerate(target) if ix in train_indices])
y_test = np.array([x for ix, x in enumerate(target) if ix in test_indices])
```

So it's your choice, happy coding :)